# Button with beveled edge on semi-transparent background

Tags: css, opacity

I'm trying to create a button with CSS that will sit on a semi-transparent background that has a beveled or cut edge to it. Here is the Photoshop mockup:

[image]

I'm able to do this successfully with a solid color background because I can use an pseudo element with that same background and "cover" the edge of the button, but it doesn't work with a semi-transparent background.

Here's what I've got so far, on a solid background: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GJFpc

I'm beginning to believe this isn't possible with just CSS, but still hoping S.O. can save me once again!

Comment: Try using the link for generating the effect from Image here: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Try for a rectangular button first and then slice it using css or the way you prefer

Comment: There might not be a good, pure CSS solution for this (see: http://codepen.io/cimmanon/pen/bvneF).  Have you considered using an SVG background?

Comment: If it's ok to specify a containing div, you can try this: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/15255561/1926369] (using a container to clip the corner)

Comment: @cimmanon - I haven't considered that. Will do.

Comment: @vals - Thanks for the link. I'll keep that for future reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I love a good css challenge so I tried a few things and this is what I could come up with:
http://jsfiddle.net/QE67v/3/

The css (unprefixed) looks like this:

```
a.cta {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    padding: 8px 10px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: normal;
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #e4e4e4 100%);
    box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 1px 2px #fff;
    line-height: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    z-index: 2;
}
a.cta:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    right: -16px;
    top: 0;
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #e4e4e4 100%);
    box-shadow: inset -3px -2px 1px 2px #fff;
    transform: skewX(-45deg);
    z-index: -1;
}
```

There are two main differences with your code:

1. I use a inset box-shadow to achieve the white 'bevel'. You could
   probably do this with gradients as well, but I just find the shadows
   more intuitive.
2. In stead of making the button wider and covering the bottom left
   corner with a pseudo element in the color of the background, I kept
   the button in its normal width and added a pseudo element to which a
   applied the skewX transformation. This allows for any background, as
   you can see by the gradient I set as a background in my fiddle.

I believe this is what you where after. Feel free to ask if you need any further help/explanation.

Comment: Wow! Great work @PeterVR. This is awesome. I've never had a use for `transform: skew`, so this is a great learning experience. Thanks!